# Download file stream as file in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stream

I have a file stream in my controller. Now I want to download such file stream as file. My code is given below....

```
<file-download file-data="{{uploadedFl.fileSrc}}"  filename="{{uploadedFl.fileName}}">
</file-download>
```

**JS**

```
 .directive('fileDownload', function() {
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         template: '<a target="_self" href="" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="downloadData()" > <i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>',
         scope: true,
         link: function(scope, element, attr) {

             var anchor = element.children()[0];
             $(anchor).attr({
                 href: attr.fileData,
                 download: attr.filename
             });
             // Also overwrite the download pdf function to do nothing.
             scope.downloadData = function() {

             };
         }
     }
 });
```

File stream is given below..

```
"data:text/plain;base64,I...AgICAgfQ=="
```

Comment: it seems you are not setting the content-disposition headers on server.. hence brower is providing you raw data

Comment: did you try `window.open(stream, '_blank', ''); `  ?

Comment: window.open works for uri not stream.

Comment: But what you are showing is a data URI

Comment: My scenario is that.. My system picks a file stream from server. After that I want to download such file stream as file by clicking any button or anchor. For this I have tried above code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use javascript Canvas. first you set stream data into canvas drawImage method then download it. like :

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

img.src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==";

var dataURL = context.toDataURL('image/png');
```

sorry! I am not getting you full code because I am busy right now. I think you use like this.